# Multiple columns unmatched query MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to find where an order number and part number combination match doesn't exist between two tables.

Basically, I have an ODBC connection downloading data from our database on a certain supplier, I also have a report of our open orders from same supplier in excel format.

I have both sets of data setup.

What I'm trying to do is find where an order number and part number combination on supplier's list does not exist on the data downloaded from our system (and vice versa in separate query but reversing the join)

I also have another separate query, checking the opposite, if any order number or part number combinations on the suppliers list that is on our data.

This is the SQL for finding unmatched combinations from suppliers list VS data from our database:

```
SELECT [Table1].[Field1], [Table1].[Field2] 
INTO s
FROM [Table1] 
LEFT JOIN [Table2] ON ([Table1].[Part No] = [Table2].Field2) AND ([Table1].[Field1] = [Table2].Field1)
WHERE ((([Table2].Field1) IS NULL) AND (([Table2].Field2) IS NULL));
```

It's basically the unmatched query wizard but adding a second column in the mix.

But for some reason, when cross referencing the results, it looks like the it's resulting in pretty much showing every record from Table1.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, hope I make sense...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It sounds like the query is working fine but the data is not what you expect.

Comment: I'll try and get some data up today, thank you

Answer (score 0):

> it looks like the it's resulting in pretty much showing every record
> from Table1

It means your `left join` on following condition is not satisfied for any of the records of `Table2`.

```
([Table1].[Part No] = [Table2].Field2) AND ([Table1].[Field1] = [Table2].Field1)
```

Which ultimately means that the `[Table2].Field1` and `[Table2].Field2` will be null in the resulting query and your `WHERE` clause (`((([Table2].Field1) Is Null) AND (([Table2].Field2) Is Null))`) becomes true for each record.

Comment: hmm, in other words, i'm going about this all wrong?